# ActionBar compat + Spinner gives SIGSEGV 11

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-studio, android-appcompat

I have an application which I've been working on for a while. It uses Google's appcompat Action Bar with Spinner navigation and it was working fine last week.

Today, I recompiled and the app crashes without as soon as I call setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST).

In logcat I see a SIGSEGV fault.

I have been able to reproduce the problem by creating a new Android Studio project using ActionBar, a blank activity with Action bar spinner navigation and absolutely nothing but the code generated by Android Studio.

I have tried using the following components:
- Android Studio 0.50.0 under Windows 8.1
- Android Studio 0.5.2 under OSX Mavericks
- Actual Android 2.3.4 hardware
- Android 2.2 Emulator under Windows
- Android 2.2 Emulator under OS X.

The problem exists on all combinations of compiler / platform.

I have also been trying to specify specific versions of appcompat in my build.gradle. But, it is the same problem regardless if I use compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1' or compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'

Does anyone have a clue as to what might be going on here?

Output from logcat and emulator running under Windows:

```
I/dalvikvm(  370): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
W/dalvikvm(  370): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 312: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm(  370): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
I/dalvikvm(  370): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
W/dalvikvm(  370): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 308: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm(  370): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
D/dalvikvm(  370): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
D/dalvikvm(  370): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 370, tid: 370  >>> com.example.actionbartest.app <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000002
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 00000000  r1 00000001  r2 00000001  r3 00000002
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 becab8a4  r5 0000aa50  r6 00116400  r7 00138eb0
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 becab914  r9 4208b814  10 4208b800  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip ad36ec18  sp becab868  lr ad349dbd  pc a81144da  cpsr 20000030
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 000144da  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 00049dba  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 00049f10  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #03  pc 00013974  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):
I/DEBUG   (   31): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   31): a81144b8 1c264337 02364016 401c4337 1c3c0a26
I/DEBUG   (   31): a81144c8 602c4334 57042403 dbea42a1 46c0bdf0
I/DEBUG   (   31): a81144d8 56c32302 56412101 230318ca 320856c3
I/DEBUG   (   31): a81144e8 008018d0 46c04770 47706800 23006802
I/DEBUG   (   31): a81144f8 d1012a00 689b6883 47701c18 21016001
I/DEBUG   (   31):
I/DEBUG   (   31): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   31): ad349d9c 9a059903 990947a0 29002400 ac0fd062
I/DEBUG   (   31): ad349dac 20007b22 2a009003 6920d02a ece4f7d2
I/DEBUG   (   31): ad349dbc 23b0682a 00981c01 1c285813 90034798
I/DEBUG   (   31): ad349dcc d1012800 e7b14843 22de6828 58430091
I/DEBUG   (   31): ad349ddc 1c282200 47989903 28009005 4d3ed103
I/DEBUG   (   31):
I/DEBUG   (   31): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab828  0000aa50  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab82c  46024df8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab830  420eace8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab834  808343a3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab838  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab83c  8086dd88  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab840  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab844  80886910  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab848  8082dba5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab84c  46024e48  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab850  00138eb0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab854  80834309  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab858  0000aa50  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab85c  00116400  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab860  df002777
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab864  e3a070ad
I/DEBUG   (   31): #01 becab868  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab86c  c0000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab870  becab914  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab874  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab878  ad36e0a8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab87c  420eace8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab880  ad374ce4  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab884  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab888  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab88c  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab890  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab894  00121ab0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab898  46024dd8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab89c  becab8c8  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8a0  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8a4  ad36dc48  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8a8  00000002
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8ac  00116400  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8b0  00000101
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8b4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8b8  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8bc  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8c0  46024df8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8c4  00116400  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8c8  ad36dd10  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8cc  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8d0  0000aa50  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8d4  80886901  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8d8  ad36e0a8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8dc  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8e0  0000aa50  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8e4  46024dd8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8e8  4208b820
I/DEBUG   (   31):     becab8ec  ad349f15  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
D/Zygote  (   33): Process 370 terminated by signal (11)
I/ActivityManager(   71): Process com.example.actionbartest.app (pid 370) has died.
```

==========================================================

Output from hardware and application compiled on Mac:

```
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): pid: 2314, tid: 2314  >>> com.example.macabtest.app <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000001
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  r0 00000000  r1 00000007  r2 fffffe84  r3 00000070
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  r4 0000abd8  r5 40547590  r6 ad376684  r7 00000001
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  r8 00219ef0  r9 00222178  10 00000001  fp 442ef280
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  ip ad3774c8  sp beb9f3c8  lr ad3515d5  pc a8115448  cpsr 20000030
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d18 42eccefa43de3400  d19 3fbc71c71c71c71c
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):  scr 60000012
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):          #00  pc 00015448  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):          #01  lr ad3515d5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): a8115428 f4026412 ea44457f ea442405 f841221c
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): a8115438 33012023 1003f990 dbea428b bf00bd30
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): a8115448 2001f990 3002f990 f99018d1 f1113003
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): a8115458 18d00208 47700080 47706800 b10b6803
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): a8115468 e0012000 68886881 bf004770 33fff04f
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): ad3515b4 f8d24629 465a71a0 46204603 f1ba47b8
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): ad3515c4 d0590f00 7030f89d 980db32f eb28f7d0
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): ad3515d4 68204601 22c0f8d0 47904620 b9104607
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): ad3515e4 4478484c 6821e7b4 22004620 3378f8d1
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): ad3515f4 47984639 b9104682 44784847 980de7a8
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f388  405475e0
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f38c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f390  405475e0
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f394  0000ce38
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f398  405475e0
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f39c  8004c053  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3a0  40547590
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3a4  442ef280
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3a8  405475e0
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3ac  8004bf39  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3b0  0000abd8
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3b4  40547590
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3b8  ad376684
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3bc  8004bf05  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3c0  df002777
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3c4  e3a070ad
I/DEBUG   ( 2267): #00 beb9f3c8  00000001
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3cc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3d0  beb9f410
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3d4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3d8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3dc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3e0  000f0d88
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3e4  40547570
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3e8  beb9f41c
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3ec  ad3760c0
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3f0  00000002
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3f4  00219ef0
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3f8  00221e01
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f3fc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f400  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f404  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f408  40547590
I/DEBUG   ( 2267):     beb9f40c  00219ef0
D/Zygote  (   54): Process 2314 terminated by signal (11)
I/ActivityManager(  127): Process com.example.macabtest.app (pid 2314) has died.
```

Comment: Try adding `android.aaptOptions.useAaptPngCruncher = true`
to your `build.gradle` file, as there is a bug in the Gradle for Android plugin related to PNG files that you may be tripping over.

Answer (score 3):

Changing gradle settings solves the problem.

Not working:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

Working:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.0'
```

See also https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67376

**Edit:**
CommonsWare's solution is neater as it works with all gradle versions:
Add `android.aaptOptions.useAaptPngCruncher = true` to the `build.gradle` file,